# R for loop overwriting variable data

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to use a for loop to create a ggplot for each column in a dataframe. I am pretty new to this so my approach may be very wrong here.

I have written a function to create the ggplot:

```
create_scatter <- function(df, x, y) {
  ggplot(df, aes(x, y)) + 
    geom_point() + 
    xlab(name) + 
    ylab("quality")
}
```

And a for loop to iterate through the Dataframe columns by name (to get the name of the column for use later) then get the contents of the column for the plotting function.

```
for (name in names(whiteWines)) {
  for (column in whiteWines[name]) {
    assign(paste0(name, "_scatter"), 
           create_scatter(whiteWines, column, whiteWines$quality))
  }
}
```

Using `assign()` I am able to create a variable name from the column name  on the fly and assign the results of ggplot to it.

I am then using grid.arrange to arrange the resulting plots in a 3 x 4 grid.

```
grid.arrange(fixed.acidity_scatter, 
             volatile.acidity_scatter, 
             citric.acid_scatter, 
             residual.sugar_scatter, 
             chlorides_scatter, 
             free.sulfur.dioxide_scatter, 
             total.sulfur.dioxide_scatter, 
             density_scatter, 
             pH_scatter, 
             sulphates_scatter, 
             alcohol_scatter,
             layout_matrix = rbind(c(1,2,3), c(4,5,6), c(7,8,9), c(10,11,12)))
```

When executed all scatter plots are created, however they all contain the data from the last scatter plot in the loop.

[Undesired Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YFNTt.png)

If I wrap the assign statement in a `print()` statement then I do get the desired outcome in the grid, but each individual plot gets printed as well.

[Desired Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nO8kC.png)

[Dataset](https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/wine-quality/winequality-white.csv)

Comment: Is there any particular reason you aren't simply reshaping your data and then using faceting?

Comment: can you share data so people can help replicate your issue?

Comment: I'm really new to this. Don't know much about R, was just trying to think logically through the process. I'll certainly have a look as faceting. Thanks!

Comment: Added link to the dataset.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're probably looking for something more like this:

```
library(readr)
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

ww <- read_delim(file = "~/Downloads/winequality-white.csv",delim = ";")

ww_long <- ww %>%
    gather(key = measure,value = value,`fixed acidity`:`alcohol`)

ggplot(data = ww_long,aes(x = quality,y = value)) + 
    facet_wrap(~measure,scales = "free_y") + 
    geom_point()
```

R has some tools that can be very tempting for beginners as they think through solving a problem. Among them are `assign()`, `get()` and `eval(parse(text = ))`. It is usually the case that a solution using those will cause more problems than they solve; there's typically a better way, but will require digging a little deeper into the "normal" way of doing things in R.

Comment: Thanks @joran! This is exactly what I'm looking for. Cleaner code and mush faster as well.

Answer (score 0):

The followings are the variables of the data
"fixed acidity";"volatile acidity";"citric acid";"residual sugar";"chlorides";"free sulfur dioxide";"total sulfur dioxide";"density";"pH";"sulphates";"alcohol";"quality"

the followings are sample rows 
7;0.27;0.36;20.7;0.045;45;170;1.001;3;0.45;8.8;6
6.3;0.3;0.34;1.6;0.049;14;132;0.994;3.3;0.49;9.5;6
8.1;0.28;0.4;6.9;0.05;30;97;0.9951;3.26;0.44;10.1;6 
7.2;0.23;0.32;8.5;0.058;47;186;0.9956;3.19;0.4;9.9;6
7.2;0.23;0.32;8.5;0.058;47;186;0.9956;3.19;0.4;9.9;6
8.1;0.28;0.4;6.9;0.05;30;97;0.9951;3.26;0.44;10.1;6 
6.2;0.32;0.16;7;0.045;30;136;0.9949;3.18;0.47;9.6;6 
7;0.27;0.36;20.7;0.045;45;170;1.001;3;0.45;8.8;6
6.3;0.3;0.34;1.6;0.049;14;132;0.994;3.3;0.49;9.5;6
8.1;0.22;0.43;1.5;0.044;28;129;0.9938;3.22;0.45;11;6
All form the excel sheet.